# Options not available anymore in my Samsung 932bw lcd

Tags: windows-7, display

I think a friend messed up something in my monitor.

I left him playing a game and when I came back, I noticed that the brightness was very high. I tried to change it but I couldn't, brightness, contrast, color warm and a few other options are marked as "not available" (he probably adjusted the brightness and changed something else too, that it's causing this thing).

I updated the monitor driver, the video card driver, plugged the monitor in other PC (I'm connected through DVI, but in the other pc I plugged through rgb) but nothing fixed it.
Is there someway to force reset all the options or something like that to fix this?

(I'm running Windows 7 but I don't think that it has something to do with it, it was working perfectly until he messed it up, and the other pc where I plugged it, runs Windows XP and the problem occurs too. And it doesn't look like a the monitor is broken, it works like it always did, just these options are marked "not available" now. )

Comment: Are these settings in Windows or in the OSD (on screen display)?
He may have set it to "custom" in the osd

Comment: In the osd, when i press the "menu" button below the monitor.
Can you better explain? Set custom in what option? What it should be then?

Answer (score 3):

On my LCD, choosing a specific color temperature/profile disables the brightness and contrast controls.

If I return it to "User", they'll all come back.

Maybe your screen is similar?

Answer (score 1):

Your monitor is set to dynamic contrast. Put it to custom. Its in the monitors settings.